# Structured data in java

Tags: java, class, data-structures, struct

In **C** I would create a data structure as below:

```
struct file_data_format
{
  char name[8][20];
  float amp[8];
  int filter[8];
};

extern struct file_data_format f_data;
```

Then I could read or write this whole structure to a file or memory location.

How would I do this in a class in java?

Answer (score 2):

You should read basics of Java before asking. Structure in C can be written as Class in Java.

```
public class FileDataFormat implements Serializable {

   String[][] name = new String[8][20];
   float[] amp = new float[8];
   int[] filter = new int[8];

   public FileDataFormat() {

   }

   public void setName(String[][] name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String[][] getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   // next getters and setters
}
```

**I pretty recommend OOP(encapsulation, polymorphism, inheritance).**

Comment: You should probably keep the array notations on those variables, given that an array of `float`s is not the same as a single `float` (same for `int`). The `name` 2D array in his code would need to be an array of 8 `String`s in the Java class. Unless OP really doesn't want arrays.

Comment: @ajp15243 anwer updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve a similar effect, you can do the following.

Unfortunately, you don't have so much control over how it's represented in memory as you do in c

```
public class file_data_format
{
  public char name[8][20];
  public float amp[8];
  public int filter[8];
}
```

...

```
public static void main()
{
    file_data_format fdf = new file_data_format();
    fdf.name = charArrayIGotFromSomewhere
}
```

Comment: +1 one since this is the only one that really mimics the ease of struct field access.  For the OP's benefit, I want to stress that breaking encapsulation like this is considered a deadly sin in the OOP realm -- private fields with public getters/setters are preferred, despite the boilerplate.

Comment: With IDE's the boilerplate can be filled with 3-4 mouse clicks. People need to know this.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FileDataFormat {
    private String name;
    private float amp;
    private int filter;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getAmp() {
        return amp;
    }

    public void setAmp(float amp) {
        this.amp = amp;
    }

    public int getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public void setFilter(int filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for reminding me why c# is superior to java

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of a struct in Java is a JavaBean, as other answers has shown you.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans), a JavaBean :

- is serializable
- has a 0-argument constructor
- allows access to properties using getter and setter methods.

To write and read it from file or memory, it is not as simple as in C. You would typically use [Java Object serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) to write/read your objects to an ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream, that could be attached to a file or a byte array.